# 'The service definition "smtp.gmail.com" does not exist.'

Tags: php, symfony, email

I just installed Symfony and there is a problem with email configuration:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\InvalidArgumentException' with message 'The service definition "smtp.gmail.com" does not exist.' in C:\Xampp\htdocs\symfony-project\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder.php:766
Stack trace:
#0 C:\Xampp\htdocs\symfony-project\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\ReplaceAliasByActualDefinitionPass.php(46): Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->getDefinition('smtp.gmail.com')
#1 C:\Xampp\htdocs\symfony-project\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\ReplaceAliasByActualDefinitionPass.php(63): Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\ReplaceAliasByActualDefinitionPass->process(Object(Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder))
#2 C:\Xampp\htdocs\symfony-project\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\ReplaceAliasByActualDefinitionPass.php(63): Symfony\Component\D in C:\Xampp\htdocs\symfony-project\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\ReplaceAliasByActualDefinitionPass.php on line 48
```

Comment: Please post your email configuration (hide/replace credentials like email/pass)

Comment: Please also edit your question to note what you do to trigger this error.

Comment: There is no any configuration for gmail on fresh symfony install, you just copy pasta some code from tutorial and don't know what happend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should share your code containing 'smtp.gmail.com' if you want help.
It can be a mistake in your configuration, or just a bug in your dependencies.

To avoid doubt, remove the following files :

- `composer.lock`
- `/vendor` (directory)
- `/app/cache/*`

And run `composer update` .
If the problem persist, verify your e-mail configuration looks like this :

```
// app/config/config.yml
swiftmailer:
    host: "%mailer_host%"
```

And

```
// app/config/parameters.yml
mailer_host: smtp.gmail.com
mailer_encryption: ssl
```

See [How use Gmail to send emails in Symfony](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/email/gmail.html)
If the problem persists, please share your configuration code in your question.